# How do I change the color on my noUiSliders depending on the value from middle

Tags: javascript, jquery, nouislider

How do I change the color from middle on my noUiSliders?

As users will drag from 0 to left or 0 right.

[image]

[Codepen Link](https://codepen.io/nags338228/pen/JLYXGV)

```
function filter500( value, type ){
    return value % 1000 ? 2 : 1;
}

    var slider = document.getElementById('range');

    noUiSlider.create(slider, {
    start: [ 0 ],
    step: 500,
    connect: [true, true],
    range: {
        'min': [ -5000 ],
        'max': [ 5000 ]
    },
    pips: {
        mode: 'steps',
        stepped: true,
        density: 4,
        filter: filter500,
        format: wNumb({
            decimals: 0,
            //prefix: '&pound;',
            negative: '',
        })
    }
});

    var connect = slider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');
var classes = ['c-1-color', 'c-2-color'];

for ( var i = 0; i < connect.length; i++ ) {
    connect[i].classList.add(classes[i]);
}


var data_value = document.getElementById('data_value');
slider.noUiSlider.on('update', function ( values, handle ) {
    data_value.innerHTML = values[handle];

});

// Read the slider value.
document.getElementById('read-button').addEventListener('click', function(){
    alert( slider.noUiSlider.get() );
    slider.setAttribute('disabled', true);
});
```

So, if user move the cursor from middle to left, the color from middle to dragged part needs to change. Any leads is much appreciated.

Comment: What value do you get back from your slider change event?

If it is a number then do a terniary like `val > 0 ? 'green' : 'red'`

Comment: slider will start from 0, if they drag to left it will be minus, else it will be plus

Comment: You really need to supply a code example for reference. We can only get so hypothetical...

Comment: Please add your code to see what you have tried or read the documentation on [noUiSliders](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-options/#section-direction)...

Comment: Updated with example. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

do you want some thing like this ?
[enter link description here](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/dmXGjJ)

```
       .c-1-color { background: red; }
       .c-2-color { background: green; }
```