# Changing noUiSlider connect color based off value condition?

Tags: javascript, css, nouislider

I'd like to [change the color of a noUiSlider connect element](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-colored-connect) when a value condition is met, and I can't figure out how to make JavaScript change the color set in the CSS:

```
.noUi-connect {
    background: green;
    }
```

Minimal example below. How can I replace `{console.log("true")}` with something that will change the connect color?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <link href="nouislider.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="notooltips.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<script src="nouislider.min.js"></script>
<script src="wNumb.js"></script>
<div id="tooltipSlider"><script>
    var tooltipSlider = document.getElementById('tooltipSlider');
    noUiSlider.create(tooltipSlider, {
    start: [1, 9],
        connect: true,
        tooltips: [true, true],
        range: {'min': 0,'max': 10}
        });</script>
<script>tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.on("change", function(){
        if (tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.get()[0] == 0) {
        console.log("true")} {console.log("false")}})</script>
</div></html>
```

Note both strings log when `tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.get()[0] == 0` seems met for reasons I don't understand, so perhaps this if statement is unsuitable. The connect element must be some color when condition is true (or slider is set to that value), another color when false.

There's already [an unaccepted answer to a similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/49303825/4107349) I don't understand. Can this be used?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems like you're placing the `<script>` block inside the div where the slider should be rendered – better place it above.

Also it seems like the `console.log("true")} {console.log("false")}})` expression needs some cleanup – after `console.log("true")}` there should be an `else`.

To change the color of the connector based on a condition you could apply a Css selector to it by selecting the respective element like:

```html
<div id="tooltipSlider"></div>

<script>
    var tooltipSlider = document.getElementById('tooltipSlider');

    noUiSlider.create(tooltipSlider, {
        start: [1, 9],
        connect: true,
        tooltips: [true, true],
        range: {'min': 0,'max': 10}
    });

    tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.on("change", function(){
        var connect = tooltipSlider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect');

        if (tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.get()[0] == 0) {
            connect[1].classList.add('noUi-connect-red');
        } else {
            connect[1].classList.remove('noUi-connect-red');
        }
    })
</script>
```

As far as i understand [the docs](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/slider-read-write/#section-reading), the condition `tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.get()[0] == 0` will be true if the first handle is set to 0. In this case, the first connector will have a width of 0 as well, so colouring it will have no visible effect.

I assume you want the visible connector to be coloured. [The NoUiSlider example](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/examples/#section-colored-connect) implies that the `connect` option takes an array of booleans to specify every connector separately. To target a specific connector you have to adapt the above code with `connect[index of connector you want to have a different color].classList...`

And in your Css:

```css
.noUi-connect {
  ​background: green;
}
.noUi-connect-red {
   background: red;
}
```

Comment: Could you please clarify what `tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.querySelectorAll('.noUi-connect')` does? I'm seeing "Uncaught TypeError: tooltipSlider.noUiSlider.querySelectorAll is not a function".

Comment: I'm sorry, this was wrong. I corrected it - the line should select all connect elements inside the slider.

Comment: Beautiful, thank you! This worked after I changed `connect[1].classList.add('noUi-connect-red')` to `connect[0]...`.

Comment: Good answer. I can add to this that the `change` event will receive the handle index as its second argument, so where the example is using `connect[1]`, that could be dynamic based on that value. Also see the [documentation on event arguments](https://refreshless.com/nouislider/events-callbacks/#section-binding).